# react + webpack - pass POST data to build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Coming from a PHP background, I used to have an index.php which does two things:

1. serve the webpage if no parameters were set;
2. or serve JSON data when a specific POST parameter was included in the request.

Something like this:

```
// -- index.php
<?php
    if ($_POST["some_parameter"]) {
        ...
        echo json_encode(someArrayData);
        exit(0);
    }
?>

<html>
    ...
</html>
```

I have built the complete frontend application with npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, and react. Having completed the first part, how can I effectively serve JSON data instead of HTML when a request includes a specific POST parameter?

I can see 2 ways of doing this:

- Build the frontend as usual and everytime I build the bundle, modify `index.html`, inject my PHP code in it, and rename it to index.php. I then would have to run this folder via apache or nginx, so I'd be able to run the index.php script. This method is downright ugly and is probably the worst way to do it.
- Run a separate PHP server which just serves data or redirects to the static webpack-generated build. All requests should then start from this server, and this server determines whether to serve data or redirect to the frontend. The problem comes to neatly passing the POST data received from the request to the static react app. As far as I know, the only way to do this would be to include a URL (GET) parameter to the redirect and manually parse it with javascript on the frontend. This is a dirty solution, in my opinion.

So, to summarize:

- I need an efficient way to get POST data in a react/webpack/webpack-dev-server environment.
- It should work with my hot-module-replacement dev setup.
- I'm fine with switching to a node-based backend like express.
- There shouldn't be any ajax involved in the static react app.

Any ideas? There has to be a way to do this properly.

Comment: Have you considered server side rendering? It would let you write your front-end in react and still serve static pages with all the content without the need of using AJAX to fetch data on demand.

Comment: @Bhargav server side rendering seems like a pretty big concept to learn for me right now, given I'm still adjusting with all the webpack + dev server + es6 + react environment. Is there a simpler way to do it?

Although thanks for pointing out that server side rendering would solve this issue, as I have server side rendering as part of my goal stack.

Comment: Not really. Plus I really don't understand the usecase of serving HTML on a GET request and JSON on a POST. That isn't the semantic way of handling resources. I suggest you look in to server side rendering using a node.js based backend like express. It shouldn't be a very big change from what you are currently doing, and it will lead to exactly what you are looking for (based on your question).

Comment: A little bit of background, I'm developing a data browser module as part of a Galaxy instance (https://galaxyproject.org/). I need to be able to pass data to and from this Galaxy instance and my app, and the app should still be completely usable without Galaxy. Galaxy only passes parameters via POST, so I have to get specifically this POST data.

Comment: Galaxy redirects the user via GET to my configured URL, where the user will supposedly browse the data on my react app. My react app will then have to POST the filter parameters made by the user back to Galaxy, then Galaxy queues this job for execution. Later, Galaxy POSTs to the same configured URL, with the filter parameters it received earlier as part of the POST request. Galaxy expects data on this response, and downloads it as CSV/TSV.

Comment: Why not have a different end point for the POST requests and a different one for GET's ? If it is a GET request redirect the user a different URL serving the static react app, if it is POST take the data and pass it on to the react app using websockets or make the app poll for data.

Comment: Within Galaxy I can only configure 1 url (I can't specify different URLs for the browser and the data source endpoint). Galaxy is enforcing this behaviour, so I have no choice but to oblige, even if it is against best practices or semantics.

I'm building a really simple 3 page application that doesn't even use or need a router because the process is entirely linear (choose dataset -> filter data -> export data or send to Galaxy). Certainly, I only need the simplest working solution and using websockets is even a more overkill solution imo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122074/discussion-between-bhargav-and-jemhuntr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I solved this by simply copying an index.php from my source directory to my build directory via the webpack config. I serve the build folder to a PHP server and keep a `webpack --watch` building my source.

I lose built-in features like auto-reload and css injection, but it's worth the convenience of not having to implement SSR for a very simple task (getting a single POST variable).

For anyone interested, I also added 2 npm scripts:

- `npm run start` runs my original webpack-dev-server with hot-reload, serving static content including a static index.html file
- `npm run static` runs the `webpack --watch` which copies the index.php file to the build directory

This lets me have hot-reloading when developing frontend, and allows POST data fetching when programming logic.

It's easy, convenient, and works on most web hosting providers.